# I have list of id's. Now i want to store them in Array to match the id

Tags: groovy

What is the process to store data in Array in Groovy Scripting

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent
def jsonsl = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)
def count= jsonsl.photos.photo.size()

for(int i =0; i<count; i++)
{
    log.info jsonsl.photos.photo[i].id

}
```

Comment: What's not working?  What's `response`?  Do you have an example bit of json?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract the ids, you should be able to do:

```
def listOfIds = jsonl.protos.photo.id
```

But without some example json for `response`, it's hard to be 100%